# want to execute first condition and then a second condition for the same parameter field

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

want to execute first condition and then a second condition for the same parameter field.

for example:

```sql
Select  
A 
B 
C 
From XYZ
Where A = case @p1 when 'All' then A else @p1 end;
      A = case when @p2 when 'Current' then @p1 else 'old'+ p@1
```

What I'm trying to do is get the value from the first parameter.  Either it is one value or all of the values in that column.  So, if I select 'All', all of the values in that column will be used for the second condition where if I select 'Current' as a value.  It will keep the select value/values else it will add the word 'old' in front of the value.

I hope I make sense as I am really a beginner.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In general for such cases you need to use qualified `OR`.

Assuming `l` is boolean flag that differentiate between 2 different logical conditions (boolean expressions), then you will have:

```sql
WHERE l AND (Condition1) OR NOT l AND (Condition2)
```

This way you do not need `CASE` or equivalent.

Comment: Would you please give an example of how the code would look like?

Comment: I believe this is exactly what my answer provided.